# Is it possible for my Russian friend to gift me a game in the UK?

Tags: steam, region-lock

Simply put, I want to get 7 Days to Die and my friend (who lives in Russia) said he will buy it for me as a gift rather than give me money because it is cheaper for him. However,  I was wondering if it is region locked? The link is [here.](http://store.steampowered.com/app/251570/)

Comment: I would be a bit careful with going between countries with games. Some games are heavily censored or different depending on which country you buy them from. See Fallout 3 or Left 4 Dead 2.

Comment: I seem to remember something about explicit restrictions for Russia and Brazil on gifting, but I don't remember if that's steam or another pc game marketplace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since 2014, Steam games bought in Russia cannot be played outside Russia.](http://www.guru3d.com/news-story/steam-is-region-locking-in-russia-due-to-low-russian-ruble.html) Valve put this restriction in place after the ruble crashed, because they didn't want to raise prices on Russian customers, but did want to prevent [arbitrage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrage) exploits like the one your friend is suggesting.

Think of the policy this way: the price is lower in Russia *only because* the games can't be bought by or gifted to non-Russian accounts. If they still could be, Valve would be forced to make the prices match prices outside Russia, and lose a lot of Russian customers due to the massive price increase.

Answer (score -1):

In this specific case, 7 Days to Die would appear to not be region locked, so your friend could send it to you. [This thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamGameSwap/comments/2ni9mm/psa_how_to_check_if_a_game_is_regionlocked/) was useful, (it was what I used to find out in this case). Basically, by tracking the game's ID down in the SteamDB, then using the subID of the various versions of products, I wasn't able to find anything that indicated that it would be locked to the region. I also found the [steam page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1266-QFZC-2141) on this subject matter, and it was quite informative.

Comment: But in the post it says that if it is bought from Russia then it can only be playable there